# Rolling sum based on all previous dates NOT previous rows sorted by date

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following dataframe:

```
+------------+--------+
|    Date    | Amount |
+------------+--------+
| 01/05/2019 |     15 |
| 27/05/2019 |     20 |
| 27/05/2019 |     15 |
| 25/06/2019 |     10 |
| 29/06/2019 |     25 |
| 01/07/2019 |     50 |
+------------+--------+
```

I need to get the rolling sum of all **previous** dates as follows:

```
+------------+--------+
|    Date    | Amount |
+------------+--------+
| 01/05/2019 | NaN    |
| 27/05/2019 | 15     |
| 27/05/2019 | 15     |
| 15/06/2019 | 35     |
| 29/06/2019 | 10     |
| 01/07/2019 | 35     |
+------------+--------+
```

Using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Date': {
            0: datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 1),
            1: datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 27),
            2: datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 27),
            3: datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 15),
            4: datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 29),
            5: datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 1),
        },
        'Amount': {0: 15, 1: 20, 2: 15, 3: 10, 4: 25, 5: 50}
    }
)
df.sort_values("Date", inplace=True)
df_roll = df.rolling("28d", on="Date", closed="left").sum()
```

Gets me:

```
+------------+--------+
|    Date    | Amount |
+------------+--------+
| 01/05/2019 |    NaN |
| 27/05/2019 |     15 | 
| 27/05/2019 |     35 | <-- Should be 15
| 15/06/2019 |     35 |
| 29/06/2019 |     10 |
| 01/07/2019 |     35 |
+------------+--------+
```

Which isn't quite correct.

How would I get the sum of all previous dates rather than all previous rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
df['new'] = df.Date.map(df.groupby('Date').Amount.sum().rolling("28d", closed="left").sum())
df
        Date  Amount   new
0 2019-05-01      15   NaN
1 2019-05-27      20  15.0
2 2019-05-27      15  15.0
3 2019-06-15      10  35.0
4 2019-06-29      25  10.0
5 2019-07-01      50  35.0
```

Comment: Thanks for this - how would I incorporate the 28 day rolling period?

Comment: @Jossy df.groupby('Date').Amount.sum().roling(....) here

Comment: Tried `df['new'] = df.Date.map(df.groupby('Date').Amount.sum().rolling("28d", on="Date"))` but getting error `ValueError: invalid on specified as Date, must be a column (of DataFrame), an Index or None`

Comment: @Jossydf['new'] = df.Date.map(df.groupby('Date').Amount.sum().rolling("28d"))

Comment: Sadly that gives another error :( `TypeError: 'Rolling' object is not callable`

Comment: @Jossy `df.groupby('Date').Amount.sum().rolling("28d").sum()`

Comment: It needed `closed="left"` but we're there! Thanks a million. Updated your answer

Comment: Just out of interest - if I wanted to apply a function to the whole dataframe to get the same result but for multiple columns - what would I do?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to aggregate your amounts by date first, then compute the rolling sum, and join this sum to the original list of dates to apply the rolling sum to all dates

```
# Aggregate (sum) by date
df_agged = (df.groupby('Date')['Amount'].agg(['sum'])
            .reset_index()
            .rename(columns={'sum':'Amount'}))
# Compute rolling sum
df_agged_rolling = df_agged.rolling("28d",on="Date",closed='left').sum()

# Join on original dates to apply rolling sum to duplicate dates
df_with_rolling_agg = df.join(df_agged_rolling.set_index('Date'),on='Date',
                              lsuffix='_orig',rsuffix='_rolling_sum')
df_with_rolling_agg

#         Date  Amount_orig  Amount_rolling_sum
# 0 2019-05-01           15                 NaN
# 1 2019-05-27           20                15.0
# 2 2019-05-27           15                15.0
# 3 2019-06-15           10                35.0
# 4 2019-06-29           25                10.0
# 5 2019-07-01           50                35.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could drop duplicate dates first, then do a rolling sum, then forward fill the resulting NaNs (occasioned by the duplicate removal):

```
df = df.assign(Amount=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Date']).rolling("28d", on="Date", closed="left")['Amount'].sum()).ffill()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        Date  Amount
0 2019-05-01     NaN
1 2019-05-27    15.0
2 2019-05-27    15.0
3 2019-06-15    20.0
4 2019-06-29    10.0
5 2019-07-01    35.0
```